# EF Core - updating an entity with a reference to itself tries to delete it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In a project I am working on, we have a class `Person` that has two properties that are references to `Person`: `CreatedById` and `UpdatedById`. When I try to update a person that has `CreatedById` or `UpdatedById` equal to the persons `Id`-property, I get this exception:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE
>   REFERENCE  constraint "FK_Persons_Persons_CreatedById"

Our person class looks something like this:

```cs
public class Person {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CreatedById))]
    public virtual Person CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UpdatedById))]
    public virtual Person UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

We also configure `Person` using the fluent API like so:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
    builder.Entity<Person>(e =>
    {
        e.HasOne(p => p.CreatedBy);
        e.HasOne(p => p.UpdatedBy);
    });
}
```

Updating a person works in all cases except the one mentioned above. When I inspect the SQL that EF generates it tries to delete the person that I am trying to update:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON
DELETE FROM [Persons]
WHERE [Id] = '{guid}'
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I put a watch on the entity that I am trying to update through the change tracker. Up until `context.SaveChanges()` is called it has the state `Modified`. As to why EF tries to delete the person when `SaveChanges` is called, I still have no idea.

Comment: Just a wild guess... have you tried using **virtual**: `public virtual Person CreatedBy { ... }` etc?

Comment: Is there a record that the deleted person is reference CreatedById or UpdatedById primary key to?

Comment: your want to delete an entity that is referenced in another entity but your update and delete are not cascade, therefore you should delete child entity first then you can delete parent entity. or can use recursive delete

Comment: @PeterB we are using *virtual* i just forgot to include it when i "simplified" the person class. updated now. 

@HamedNaeemaei I am not trying to delete a person, I am trying to update it. EF generates this delete when I update an a person with an `Id` equal to `CreatedById` or `UpdatedById`...

Comment: Which exactly request do you make?

Comment: @andbjer Please edit your question to include the full source code you have, which can be compiled and tested by others. The source code should show exactly how you try to insert and update the entities you have and where the exception is thrown. Also include the full exception stacktrace to your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for adding your source code to your question.